# Multiple applications in single Tomcat vs multiple instances of tomcat

Tags: web-applications, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Currently, we run multiple applications in a single Tomcat

I would rather run each application as a single application with embedded Tomcat

Does anyone see any downside to this ?

I am guessing my per instance need for Memory will go down- so my over-all memory consumption will basically remain the same.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: did you implement the multi-instance solution? If so, what was the net effect on memory usage? I am looking to do the same in a multi-host environment, but if I have to dedicate 512mb per instance (like Grails for example), 12GB available ram will go quickly.

Answer (score 5):

I think you will need more memory overall as each application will need to have its breathing space. You will also probably have to do more maintenance as the amount of config files will go up.

At this cost you will get more independence - e.g. if one of the apps will suck all CPU resources or even manage to bring down entire JVM, your other Tomcats will still be up and running.

Comment: Another drawback is you'll have to run every application on distinct port, you can't communicate with them all on just port 80 or 8080 when using multiple Tomcat instances